# In java, how do I add line breaks to a JButton's tooltip?

Tags: java, string, jbutton, jcomponent

I have a `JButton` that uses `setToolTipText(String str)` and I have a few lines of writing in the tooltip that need to to be separated by line breaks. I tried concatenating + "/n" at the end of each line of text right before I wanted the line break to go, but it did not do anything. `JToolTip` text doesn't have a constructor with a `JTextArea` and I couldn't see anything in `JTextArea` that allowed it to convert to a `String`. Anyone have any ideas?
Also, how do I get a `JToolTip` to last longer than the default 3 seconds? 
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use HTML.

Set the tooltip to `"<html>My multi-line<br>tooltip.</html>"`